# Facebook Login With Flutter

Tags: facebook, dart, flutter, hybrid

```
Future<FirebaseUser> login({List<String> userData, var loginCallback, var cancelledCallback,
        var errorCallback}) async {
    var facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
    var facebookLoginResult = await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);
    switch (facebookLoginResult.status) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
        print("Error");
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        print("CancelledByUser");
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        print("LoggedIn");
        break;
    }
  }
```

Using flutter_facebook_login plugin and it always throws this error.Couldn't figure out where am i going wrong. Here is the logcat for the error.

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method loginWithReadPermissions on channel com.roughike/flutter_facebook_login)
E/flutter ( 6174): #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:278:7)
E/flutter ( 6174): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6174): #1      FacebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions (package:flutter_facebook_login/flutter_facebook_login.dart:101:23)
E/flutter ( 6174): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6174): #2      FacebookAuth.login (package:shout_out/util/social_login.dart:26:25)
```

Comment: Hope u reinstalled/restarted the app. Hot recode will have the above problem

Comment: Still get an error. In my logcat The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.

Caused By 
    at io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:19)at com.ujjwalmainali.shoutout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)at io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:19) at com.ujjwalmainali.shoutout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)

Comment: okay i solved it by adding the app_id in AndroidManifest.xml file inside <application> tag. thanks for your answer. it was due to hot restart.

Answer (score 9):

MissingPluginException usually occurs when you add a plugin and doesnt re-run your app from the start.

Try to kill your application and again run it. The problem will go away.

**Edit**

Facebook sdk for flutter requires to have some additions in your manifest file (For android), the changes are documented in the plugin documentation.

Answer (score 2):

**AndroidX support #**

if you don't know what android X is, Simply use this one (1.2.0) and the Error will be Solved

*if you want to avoid AndroidX, use version 1.2.0.*

• **flutter_facebook_login: ^1.2.0**

if you want to use the latest version please refer about Android X

*for AndroidX Flutter projects, use versions 2.0.0 and up.*

• **flutter_facebook_login: ^2.0.0**

Answer (score 1):

For android studio go to the file > invalidate caches / restart.....

it is working for me so, I hope it will work for you...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Facebook Developer Account and make sure all the functionality you have linked with firebase or not Then try